# Tidying up lambda expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

The following code gives me the results I need, but can anyone suggest how to write it better? I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it.
Thanks.

```
private bool IsLocation(Guid _vID, Guid OrganisationId)
{
    var vehicle = _vehilceRepository.GetSingle(c => c.vehicleId == _vID);
    var clients = _clientRepository.GetList(c => c.OrganisationID == OrganisationId);

    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        var locations = _LocationRepository.GetList(c => c.ClientID == client.ClientID);
        if (locations.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var location in locations)
            {
                if (location.LocationId == vehicle.LocationID)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend installing `ReSharper` for Visual Studio. It will help you with these kinds of things.

Comment: What do you mean by: "more efficient way"? Faster code execution (which in fact is efficiency) or less code to write?

Comment: To echo what @AdamJachocki says - the *ideal* here would be to be able to do a single operation (rather than N+2); that, however, is not necessarily readily available via a repository API. This is why I usually prefer *very* specific methods when performance is a factor - i.e. so I can essentially write some SQL that does that *directly* via joins at the database, passing just the two guids in, and just returning 1 or 0. So I guess the ideal here is: `return _someRepo.IsVehicleInAnyClientLocation(_vID, OrganisationId);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var vehicle = _vehilceRepository.GetSingle(c => c.vehicleId == _vID);
var clients = _clientRepository.GetList(c => c.OrganisationID == OrganisationId);
return clients.SelectMany(client => _LocationRepository.GetList(
                c => c.ClientID == client.ClientID))
       .Any(location => location.LocationId == vehicle.LocationID);
```

?

Comment: OP asked for more efficient way. LINQ will NEVER be as efficient as standard loop

Comment: @Adam oh *please*... by the time you've done n+2 repository operations, it is **totally irrelevant** how you iterate over it, and pretending that you're worrying about efficiency there is silly. So to my mind that leaves the other kind of efficiency: the efficiency of having less, simpler code. The OP asks about "write it better" and "tidying up" - I suggest that this has a fair stab at that. Amusingly, I'm probably the first person to **uglify** code for performance, but that's when I'm dealing with purely in-memory data. Go to a DB: forget about everything else.

Comment: @AdamJachocki it's not clear what he means by efficient, because the title

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will try this out shortly

Comment: OK it seems that the answer is what OP looked for. So I will grade up as soon as I can.